# Pandas read_csv skipping to new line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading a csv file into pandas (v 0.23.4), and for some reason, for only one specific row out of 100,000 rows, halfway through the row, a new line(s) is created. I've tried changing the delimiter to semi-colon and reading in a tab-delimited text file, but the same issue arises. I've also looked at the raw data to see if there are any funky characters but everything looks normal.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
csv_file:
AccountNumber,State,Sector,Subsector1234,CA,Retail,Restaurant

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
AccountNumber State Sector Subsector
1234          CA
NaN           Retail
NaN           Restaurant
```

Comment: There is an non-printable character that is mucking it up.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-printable character?

Comment: [see this](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) for a reference.  When I copy and paste what you have above, it parses fine.  You don't see it when you print it because it is a character that doesn't get printed out.  I can't tell you exactly what's going on, but that is the clue I can offer.

Comment: Yeah, I had to change the data since it's sensitive customer information. Is there a way to determine whether there are non-printable characters?

Comment: You need to scrub your file somehow.  If this process isn't automated, I normal doing it by copy all into my buffer, paste in Notepad the copy from Notepad and paste into a new clean cvs file.  This would be just a test to see if non-printable characters really are the problem.

Comment: I exported to the data to Excel instead of csv and Pandas read it as expected. Is there a reason this would happen?